# Poker Chip Alternative

Tags: custom-game-pieces

I'm looking for a chip- or coin-like item that has the following qualities of poker chips, but without the association with gambling:

- high quality materials
- approximately same size and weight (not paper)
- attractive design
- multiple colors

Does anyone know of something like this?

Comment: POGS (The slammers)- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milk_caps_(game) - Mind you it could be associated with Gambling too.

Comment: Not sure what the policy is regarding commercial links...
I know of a few companies that propose this kind of stuff but wouldn't want to break any rules here...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a subjective shopping list/recommendation question.

Comment: I wish that the OP had told us why they asked this, before disappearing forever. Chips, even customized, are, as the Brits say, "[as cheap as chips](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=poker+chips&_sacat=0)".

Answer (score 6):

Most games of checkers have cool designs and stack and are pretty durable. They're obviously not poker chips. They generally only come in red or black, but I've spray painted them different colors to make generic Magic the Gathering tokens (the fact that they stack is nice for things that make lots of 1/1 dudes...) and they come out pretty good. Just a quick coat, let it dry, flip it and do another quick coat.

You can often buy checkers games for cheap from thrift stores.

Comment: Great idea for the MtG tokens.... I might have to make some of those now.

Comment: The silver spray painted checkers of mine for artifact tokens came in super handy for both clues and now recently in Kaladesh too.

Answer (score 5):

Tiddlywinks.

You can buy small plastic discs from most toyshops.

Answer (score 2):

Some Connect-Four chips are pretty much the same as poker chips, they even stick together in a cool way; that's the case for the ones made by MB.

Comment: How strict is the non-commercial rule here? Can I name the brand instead of doing that ridiculous riddle?

Comment: Generally it is only an issue if you are promoting your own product and don't disclose that fact.

Comment: Ok, I'll name it then.